# If a vampire would stand inside a house when it was built would he be able to leave?

Tags: vampire

Take a vampire from a series that can't enter a house without permission, for example, *The Vampire Diaries* and *True Blood*, what would happen if it was standing inside the house while it was being built?

Comment: I think this is too vague and speculative. Vampire rules on the issue already vary greatly from work to work, but then you also have the problem of determining at what point in the construction a house is actually defined as *a house*. Is it when the frame goes up? When the front door is hung? When the final bathroom fixture is in place? And how do you interpret the idea of "permission" or "an invitation" if a house isn't yet occupied?

Comment: @gnovice - one thing you CAN answer with certainty is when it's a house. I'm 99.9% certain some bureaucrat somewhere on some level of government defined what a house is for some law or regulation, with excruciating teeth-pulling detail.

Comment: @DVK: True, there is likely some *bureaucratic* definition for "a house", but I doubt innate vampire behavior is bureaucracy-based. ;)

Comment: I like this question. I'm sad it's closed.

Comment: @gnovice - I wanna be a vampire then!

Comment: I would go for a "spiritual" answer - a building becomes a house only after someone moves in and calls it a home. And who'll move in to a home with a vampire hanging around inside??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since the restriction is on *entering* a house, not leaving it, there's no reason he wouldn't be able to *leave*.